# To get confirmation from c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

When the user clicks Import button on OnClick java script function, im getting confirmation message to continue. After that, if the input value is already existing in the database. i need to get confimation from user 'you want to overwrite', if they click yes i should continue the process delete and insert new information.

Intermediate C# code how can i get user confirmation? After checking the the input value with databse i need confirmation.

i tried to use like this,

```
if (MessageBox.Show(".Do you want to overwrite?",
    "Dialog Box", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
```

Its working in my local,but when i moved to server its not working.

Could you tell any idea to solve this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You have confuse the code that run a desktop computer, or the server, and the part of the code that runs on the client browser. The MessageBox is a function that creates a dialog on the desktop/server. What you need to call using javascript is the `confirm` a similar dialog that runs and lives on browsers.

By placing this code on a button you can have a confirmation before the submit.

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to overwrite?')"
```

If how ever you need to check some more on code behind then you need to return to the user a new confirmation and make the user click again.

Comment: Yes i need to get second confimation from user if the code is already existing in DB. First confirmation i got when user clicks the button, so i dont know how to get confimation intermediate C# code(how to call java script message and how to get return value in c#).